# Connecting a private IP and a Public IP through one server on dual NIC

Tags: networking, centos

I have a Centos box with dual onboard Ethernet ports. My hopes are to have Eth0 as the Public IP coming from the ISP Bridged router and Eth1 connected to a local router for internal purposes. Currently it is not working that way. They act like they are bonded together. I did not do that when i set it up. What i want to know is if it is possible to do that and how should they be set up - Bridged, isolating, or Gatewaying. The public IP will be tied to a domain name and i want to be able to access the other port internally for use as a development area. thank you.

Update 6/14/2014 8:23 EST
Version of CentOS is 6.6 I386
Currently right now i disabled or changed the eth0 to an internal address. So a link would not be helpful.
Below is the traceroute of the private IP in use
traceroute to 192.168.1.10 (192.168.1.10), 30 hops max, 38 byte packets 1 Linksys09562 (192.168.1.1) 3010.341 ms !H 3009.795 ms !H 3019.864 ms !H Trace complete

If there is more information needed just ask.

Update 6/14/2015 10:05 EST
Eth0:
IPVINIT=no
HWADDR=00:30:48:B3:97:56
UUID=c5487d70-8371-4012-addd-3a59c8bf72eb
BOOTPROTO=dhcp
NM_CONTROLLED=no
TYPE=ethernet
DEVICE=eth0
DEFROUTE=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=yes
ONBOOT=yes

ETH1:
GATEWAY=192.168.1.1
IPVINIT=no
HWADDR=68:05:CA:33:42:82
BROADCAST=192.168.1.255
DNS1=192.168.1.1
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
IPADDR=192.168.1.10
UUID=27d87da2-ebb5-4b5d-b370-ad960719e667
BOOTPROTO=none
NM_CONTROLLED=no
TYPE=ethernet
DEVICE=eth1
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=yes
ONBOOT=yes

/etc/network/interfaces - does not exist.

Comment: add following details: version of centos, output of 'ip addr' 'ip route' and 'ip link'

Comment: We're still waiting for the information that dmourati asked for.

Comment: That information is in the paragraph dated 6/14/2014 8:23 EST. If i am missing something let me know and i will post it. I did traceroute if that is not what is wanted please explain. thanks